# ruby how to generate a tree structure form array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, algorithm, tree

I have a array which have list of item like this

```
arr = [
  {:id=>1,  :title=>"A",      :parent_id=>nil}, 
  {:id=>2,  :title=>"B",      :parent_id=>nil},
  {:id=>3,  :title=>"A1",     :parent_id=>1}, 
  {:id=>4,  :title=>"A2",     :parent_id=>1},
  {:id=>5,  :title=>"A11",    :parent_id=>3}, 
  {:id=>6,  :title=>"12",     :parent_id=>3},
  {:id=>7,  :title=>"A2=121", :parent_id=>6}, 
  {:id=>8,  :title=>"A21",    :parent_id=>4},
  {:id=>9,  :title=>"B11",    :parent_id=>2}, 
  {:id=>10, :title=>"B12",    :parent_id=>2},
   ...
]
```

If `parent_id` is `nil` then its should be the parent node, if `parent_id` is not `nil` then it should comes under the particular parent.

Based on `id` and `parent_id`, I want to provide a response like this:

```
-A
  -A1
    -A11
    -A12
      -A123
  -A2
    -A21
-B
  -B1
    -B11
    -B12
```

How could I generate a responds mentioned above?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Rails project?

Comment: yes, its a Rails 3.0.3 project

Comment: You could use a gem like https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry or https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree, both can generate a nested hash

Comment: thanks for the support, is it possible to generate it without adding any fields in database?

Comment: Closure_tree works with a `parent_id` column, you just have to set up an additional table and run a rake task, see https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree#installation

Comment: And... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Question is unclear. What is the rule that changes the title `"12"` into `"A12"` and `"A2=121"` into `"A123"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

root = {:id => 0, :title => '', :parent_id => nil}

arr = arr = [
  {:id=>1,  :title=>"A",      :parent_id=>nil}, 
  {:id=>2,  :title=>"B",      :parent_id=>nil},
  {:id=>3,  :title=>"A1",     :parent_id=>1}, 
  {:id=>4,  :title=>"A2",     :parent_id=>1},
  {:id=>5,  :title=>"A11",    :parent_id=>3}, 
  {:id=>6,  :title=>"12",     :parent_id=>3},
  {:id=>7,  :title=>"A2=121", :parent_id=>6}, 
  {:id=>8,  :title=>"A21",    :parent_id=>4},
  {:id=>9,  :title=>"B11",    :parent_id=>2}, 
  {:id=>10, :title=>"B12",    :parent_id=>2},
]

map = {}

arr.each do |e|
  map[e[:id]] = e
end

@@tree = {}

arr.each do |e|
  pid = e[:parent_id]
  if pid == nil || !map.has_key?(pid)
    (@@tree[root] ||= []) << e
  else
    (@@tree[map[pid]] ||= []) << e
  end
end

def print_tree(item, level)
  items = @@tree[item]
  unless items == nil
    indent = level > 0 ? sprintf("%#{level * 2}s", " ") : ""
    items.each do |e|
      puts "#{indent}-#{e[:title]}"
      print_tree(e, level + 1)
    end
  end
end

print_tree(root, 0)
```

Output:

```
-A
  -A1
    -A11
    -12
      -A2=121
  -A2
    -A21
-B
  -B11
  -B12
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use a gem like [Closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree):

> `hash_tree` provides a method for rendering a subtree as an ordered
>   nested hash:
>
> ```
> Tag.hash_tree
> #=> {a => {b => {c1 => {d1 => {}}, c2 => {d2 => {}}}, b2 => {}}}
> ```

Or [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry):

> Ancestry can arrange an entire subtree into nested hashes for easy
>   navigation after retrieval from the database. `TreeNode.arrange` could
>   for example return:
>
> ```
> { #<TreeNode id: 100018, name: "Stinky", ancestry: nil>
>   => { #<TreeNode id: 100019, name: "Crunchy", ancestry: "100018">
>     => { #<TreeNode id: 100020, name: "Squeeky", ancestry: "100018/100019">
>       => {}
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

See https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting for other gems.

#### Update

If you have to do it in-memory, something like this should work:

```
nested_hash = Hash[arr.map{|e| [e[:id], e.merge(children: [])]}]
nested_hash.each do |id, item|
  parent = nested_hash[item[:parent_id]]
  parent[:children] << item if parent
end
tree = nested_hash.select { |id, item| item[:parent_id].nil? }.values

require 'pp'
pp tree
```

Output

```
[{:id=>1,
  :title=>"A",
  :parent_id=>nil,
  :children=>
   [{:id=>3,
     :title=>"A1",
     :parent_id=>1,
     :children=>
      [{:id=>5, :title=>"A11", :parent_id=>3, :children=>[]},
       {:id=>6,
        :title=>"12",
        :parent_id=>3,
        :children=>
         [{:id=>7, :title=>"A2=121", :parent_id=>6, :children=>[]}]}]},
    {:id=>4,
     :title=>"A2",
     :parent_id=>1,
     :children=>[{:id=>8, :title=>"A21", :parent_id=>4, :children=>[]}]}]},
 {:id=>2,
  :title=>"B",
  :parent_id=>nil,
  :children=>
   [{:id=>9, :title=>"B11", :parent_id=>2, :children=>[]},
    {:id=>10, :title=>"B12", :parent_id=>2, :children=>[]}]}]
```

Comment: both gems are really awesome, can we make it without any database migrations?

Answer (score 5):

Don't mean to replace proven gems, but depending on your needs you can use something as simple as:

```
groups = arr.group_by{ |x| x[:parent_id] }
groups.default = []

build_tree = 
  lambda do |parent| 
    [parent[:title], groups[parent[:id]].map(&build_tree)]
    # or
    # { parent[:title] => groups[parent[:id]].map(&build_tree) }
  end

p build_tree[:id => nil][1] # :id => nil is not required, empty hash will work too
# => [["A", [["A1", [["A11", []], ["A12", [["A122", []]]]]], ["A2", [["A21", []]]]]], ["B", [["B11", []], ["B12", []]]]]
```

Comment: thanks for your time, its complicated for me to understand the concept behind build_tree.